# Using subset function with nested conditions in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I'm working on translating some SQL queries into R. I'm more adept in SQL than R, but I need to switch to R due to powers greater than me, so I apologize if this is basic R stuff. I wasn't able to find any similar questions on here that fixed my issue.

I have a data table in the following format (first line is column names, second line is data):

```
CID, DID, SID, ECSTART, ECEND, EC, LASTASSIGNED, LASTCLOSE
123, 456, 789, 2017-05-02, 2018-03-20, John Smith, 2014-06-01, 2018-05-01
```

I have a SQL query that counts distinct CIDs for each EC with some constraints:

```
SELECT EC, COUNT(DISTINCT CID)
FROM dbo.table
WHERE ECSTART < '2018-09-01'
AND (ECEND > '2018-09-30' OR ECEND IS NULL)
AND LASTASSIGNED < '2018-09-01' AND (LASTCLOSE > '2018-09-30' OR LASTCLOSE IS NULL)
AND DID != '999999'
GROUP BY EC
ORDER BY EC
```

This query gives me my expected result. It seemed like using the subset function in R would be the way to make all of those conditions work in R. My attempt:

```
table(subset(data$EC, data$ECSTART < '2018-09-01'
         & (data$ECEND > '2018-09-30' | is.null(data$ECEND))
         & data$LASTASSIGNED < '2018-09-01'
         & (data$LASTCLOSE > '2018-09-30' | is.null(data$LASTCLOSE))
         & data$DID != 999999))
```

The R code runs without error, but it gives me the completely wrong result. I tried running the R code piece-by-piece to see what's happening, and it seems like it might be pulling out subsets in a fundamentally different way than the WHERE clause in the SQL query is. I could have a misunderstanding of the way the subset function works, but everything I've read in ?subset and searching online makes me think it *should* work, maybe just in a different way than I'm using it. I'm completely open to using other R functions if they're better fit for this case.

I also tried using the SQL I started with in R by wrapping it in a sqldf function and using the sqldf library. When I run that, it doesn't error out or produce any results, this is all it spits out:

```
[1] EC                  COUNT(DISTINCT CID)
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload a sample of your data using `dput()`?

Comment: What you think of as NULL in a SQL db is NA in R, not NULL. The object NULL in R is different. So at the very least you want `is.na()` not `is.null()`.

Comment: Secondly, the use of `subset()` on a single column sort of give me the heebie-jeebies. I suppose it works, but it's not really the _intended_ use, and seems like an easy way to make a mistake with `subset()`'s non-standard evaluation. Nowadays, people do simple grouping counts like this in R with **dplyr** or **data.table** packages, the syntax of each would make _way_ more sense to you coming from SQL.

Comment: Regarding the SQL statement which the question says was run using sqldf, the  `dbo.table` should be the name of the input data.frame and the one record input shown  does not satisfy the `ECEND` conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the difference between null and na in SQL vs R world and for the note on using subset(). Definitely helps me make sense of R a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't assure you that this will work, because I don't have a reproducible example to test it on, but the **dplyr** way to approach this sort of thing would look like this:

```
data %>%
    filter(CSTART < '2018-09-01'
                 & (ECEND > '2018-09-30' | is.na(ECEND))
                 & LASTASSIGNED < '2018-09-01'
                 & (LASTCLOSE > '2018-09-30' | is.na(LASTCLOSE))
                 & DID != 999999)) %>%
    group_by(EC) %>%
    summarise(n = n_distinct(CID))
```

which might seem more sensible if you're coming from SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just had to do some really minor edits to this, but it worked! The dplyr library looks fantastic and definitely more approachable too (for me at least). I'll definitely be leaning on this library more in the future, thanks for introducing me to it.